# How to analyse multiple measurements for two dependent variables

Tags: spss, repeated-measures, multivariate-analysis

I'm having trouble finding the best way to prove a significant relationship between tap pressure (on a screen) and emotion (Valence/Arousal). The research question could be formulated as this in a nutshell: *Can tap pressure predict emotion?*

**Test setup:**
Every participant is shown 60 pictures from which a known emotion response is elicited (i.e. every photo has valence and arousal value, both between 0.0 and 100.0). At every photo, they perform a tap of which pressure is measured. See the picture below for an example of how the data looks. Every row is a seperate photo, columns are valence and arousal values of the photo, the numbered columns are participant results. In the example you see six columns for tap pressure, in reality I have 204 columns for every photo.

[image: Example data. Every row is a seperate photo, columns are valence and arousal values of the photo, the numbered columns are participant results.]

My question is: **What is the best approach/method to discover a significant (or not) relation between tap pressure and valence/arousal values?**

I already tried to average the pressure of all taps, and use that as single independent variable for every picture (see picture below). This way I could apply multiple linear regression, but I can't help but feel that this is an inadequate approach considering the amount of data I gathered.

[image: First attempt]

Is there any other method that allows me to use all collected data rather than averaging it all?

Comment: Do you want to predict `tap pressure` based on `valence` & `arousal`, or do you want to predict `valence` & `arousal` based on `tap pressure`? You say you have "240 columns for every photo", do you mean that you collected responses from 240 people?

Comment: I want to predict valence & arousal based on tap pressure. I have indeed collected 204 responses.

Comment: In that case your topic is misleading. Change independent to dependent.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight I am not sure why? The tap pressure is my dependent variable, the valence and arousal values is what I manipulate (i.e. I know them already) therefor independent.. right?

Comment: If you are trying to predict valence & arousal based on tap pressure, then V & A are the response variables. Using standard terminology, that makes TP your independent variable. Are V & A correlated?

Comment: Yes, they show strong correlation using Pearson ( -0.824 with p > 0.001)

Comment: Am I correct to assume that my first order of business is to show that there is indeed a meaningful relation between TP and V&A?